# Не отображаются русские буквы

Tags: консоль, git-bash

[image: ошибка]

В чем может быть проблема? Раньше работало все нормально, а сейчас русские буквы отображаются в виде таких знаков. Шрифты менял, не помогло.

Comment: Кодировка выбрана неверная. Скорее всего, там utf8

Comment: @ilyaplot , а какую нужно выбрать?

Comment: Я же написал, utf8

Comment: @ilyaplot , не так написал. Имел в виду, где найти эту настройку, чтобы ее поменять, ни где не могу найти.

Comment: В настройках соединения(консоли), видимо. Я даже не могу понять, что за софт на скриншоте

Comment: @ilyaplot Это conemu, но проблема вряд ли в ней, потому что я открываю gitbash, там тоже самое.